# Flask: how to implement a general searchbar for every view, without rewriting it?

Tags: python, url, get, flask, searchbar

I have a Problem to implement my search bar. I have it in my base template, an get a returnvalue over the get attribute ?search=

my Problem is now, that I want to use the searchbar from every site in my project without rewrite the searchcall in every single view.

is there a way to only write it once?

If it helps, my searchbarcode:

```
<input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
```

Comment: What is the `action` attribute of your `form` tag?

Comment: had none, this actually helps alot. I'm now using `action="/search/"` in my form tag. And it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add an `action` attribute to your `form` tag. This will allow you to point all searches at one view.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}">
```

You can then include something along these lines with your views.

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    query = request.args('search')
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick update to the above, it looks like later versions of Flask needs different syntax.

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    query = request.args('search')
```

throws

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' object is not callable
```

I used square brackets around the args instead and that resolved the error

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    query = request.args['search']
```